# Numpy Throwing Truth Value Error when trying to check count of a specific number for use in a partial Sudoko checker

Tags: python, numpy

Hi I am trying to create a partial Sudoku checker and using numpy am trying to count all instances of zeros in a row/column in order to check the set count against it. I am getting a truth value error when I do this.

```
def sodoku(n):
    if (n > 9).all() and (n < -1).all():
        return False
    for i in range(0, 9):
        j = (i // 3) * 3
        k = (i % 3) * 3
        if len(set(n[i, :])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1))) or len(set(n[:, i])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0))) or len(
                set(n[j:j + 3, k:k + 3].reshape(-1))) != (9 - ((np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1)) + (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0)))):
            return False
    return True
board = [[1, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
        [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
        [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7]]
a = np.asarray(board)
print(sodoku(a))
```

Here is the traceback

```
(base) omega@Jamess-MacBook-Air Downloads % python assign2.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assign2.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(sodoku(a))
  File "assign2.py", line 22, in sodoku
    if len(set(n[i, :])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1))) or len(set(n[:, i])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0))) or len(
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When broken up there is still the same issue

```
        a = len(set(n[i, :])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1)))
        b = len(set(n[:, i])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0)))
        c = len(set(n[j:j + 3, k:k + 3].reshape(-1))) != (9 -
                                                          ((np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1)) + (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0))))
        if a:
            if b:
                if c:
                    return False
    return True
```

with traceback appended

```
(base) omega@Jamess-MacBook-Air Downloads % python assign2.py                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assign2.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(sodoku(a))
  File "assign2.py", line 26, in sodoku
    if a:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Please post a complete traceback. Including an indication of where it occurs.

Comment: Where does this error occur - full traceback.  I assume this is the common Ambiguity error.  But you've already done something about that in the first `if` with `all`.  Is the error in the 2nd `if`?

Comment: yes sorry this is the second one, I will post full traceback my bad

Comment: python assign2.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assign2.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(sodoku(a))
  File "assign2.py", line 22, in sodoku
    if len(set(n[i, :])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1))) or len(set(n[:, i])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0))) or len(
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: The 2nd condition is long.  I'd suggest breaking it into pieces so you can identify exactly which comparison is giving the problem

Comment: Hi and welcome! The code example you provided is very hard to read. Possibly cut up the logic that is all found in line 7. This in general good practice, and will most likely help you narrow your search for the source of the error. When you know exactly what expression that causes the exception you may be able to solve your prblem, or ask about it here, if you do not understand why a specific exception is generated by a specific expression.

Comment: The use of `or` and `and` needs care.  Put () around all comparisons, so they are performed before you try to combine them logically.  Like `if` `and/or` do not like array values.

Comment: Suggestion: compute each of the `or` conditions as a separate variable and print each one separately. E.g.: `a = len(set(n[i, :])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=1)))`, `b = len(set(n[:, i])) != (9 - (np.count_nonzero(n == 0, axis=0)))` or so. Then `print(a, b, ...)`, and `if a or b or ...:`

Comment: This will show you which condition is causing you a problem. Or it will make the problem go away entirely because of the grouping that hpaulj is referring to.

Comment: Ok I have tried this am getting the error at the first switch statement

Comment: Could you update to show what you've tried? Since there are no answers, you will not be invalidating anyone's work at this point.